# Why does printing a[0][:0:] give me a different answer than printing a[0][0] ? (Python multi-Dimensional array)

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

lets say I have array a where:

```
a = [[1.0,2.5,3.0],[2.0,5.0,3.0]]
```

why does doing `print a[0][:0:]` output:

```
[]
```

meanwhile doing `print a[0][0]` outputs(the first Item in the first array within the array): `[1.0]`

I eventually want to take moving averages of multi-dimensional arrays. I want to make sure I understand the syntax first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `print a[0][0]` refers to the first element on 2d in the first element of 1d.

This `print a[0][:0:]` refers to slice notation:

```
a[start:end] # items start through end-1
a[start:]    # items start through the rest of the array
a[:end]      # items from the beginning through end-1
a[:]         # a copy of the whole array
```

[Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation)

Answer (score 3):

For the same reason that `[1, 2, 3][0]` gives a different answer to `[1, 2, 3][:0:]`.

`[0]` will give the element at index 0, `[:0:]` (or more simply `[:0]`) will give all the elements from the start of the list to *before* the element at index 0 (which is en empty list of course).

`[0]` is an index lookup, and `[:0:]` is slice notation, so they are quite different things.